# Protect FTP folders and

Tags: ftp

I have multiple people accessing my FTP server and i want to protect some folders inside this FTP server with a password.

So the people that are inside the FTP server only can acces the protected the folder with a password.

can someone tell me how to do that please ?

Comment: Why not simply have different users, with different access rules?

Comment: From a ftp server you can't do that, what you can do is enable the anonymous user and folder so the users can access the anonymous folder and only users that know the username and password will be able to access what is outside from it on that given user directory. You could aswell change the user and group of a given file and its permission so others won't be able to access or read it.

Comment: Another thing that is possible is to use a ftp server with chrooted folders which means every user you have will be closed inside their folder and won't be able to go outside it, being able to only access what is inside it. **You can easyly do this with all ftp servers available for linux but perhaps you want to give us more information of what your GOAL is and what is the OS you are dealing with**

Answer (score 0):

What ftp software are you using? This is pretty easy to do with Filezilla Server's GUI manager.  IIS isn't bad either, but because it integrates into Windows you'll need to make a new account for all your users and use the built-in security settings to isolate the users.